# Latexdiff with two column layout

Tags: latexdiff

I'm trying to use latexdiff-so on a document using the two-column Elsevier style. Unfortunately, latexdiff does not respect the column boundaries, and as a result some changes overflow deep from the left into the right column. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: It is hard to say without a MWE but this probably is relates to citations because ulem does not play that well with citation commands. Try using -t CFONT (will lose you the underline and strike-out but still get color highlighting) or --disable-citation-markup option (changes to citations are no longer marked up with this)

Comment: No, the problematic line contains inline equations, but no citations. I'll try the options you mentioned later today, and see if I can put together a MWE. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the offending text by manually adding a line break in the output of latexdiff.